# how to get theprofile name in triggers when saved?

Tags: trigger, user-admin, custom-profile

one user have four profiles and one custom object with one field each time when the record is saved for the fifferent different prifiles,after it saved it shows with the profile name in salesforce.

Comment: Can you expand your question? How can a user have 4 profiles? It isn't clear from your question what you are trying to do.

Comment: each time user can login with different profile and add the data in the object when it saves automatically it shows the created by --- profile name

Comment: So instead of the user name, you want the created by to display a profile name instead?

Comment: yes right... Daniel

Answer (score 1):

CreatedBy is a read only field that cannot be modified by a trigger. It will always display the user name. You could add a formula field that displays the createdby user's profile name.

> CreatedBy.Profile.Name

Comment: can you send the programme on triggers plz.... iam new to sfdc

Comment: You don't need a trigger for it. Just add a formula field to the object with the above formula.

Comment: If my answer helped, please upvote and accept.